# UINavigationBar's title animation between screens

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have created a popover with a few screens all controlled with a navigation controller.  I have seen examples of this done and in these examples when you change between screens, the title and 'done' button of the navigation bar are always in the same position and never animate.  The only changes that occur is a 'back' button that appears.

I have attempted to mimic the same behavior but things aren't quite exact.

Whenever screens transition, the title and done button swipe to the left and fade just like the view's normal animation.  I need them to stay put and only the view animate.  Also, the 'back' button that is being auto generated ( I am not creating it, but one IS being created by the navbar) is labeled the previous screen's title.  I need it to simply be 'back.'  How do I customize the auto generated button?  or at least halt its creation so I can create a button myself?

some code...

```
 //popover and navbar creation

SettingsPopoverView *settingsPopoverView = [[SettingsPopoverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsPopoverView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                               initWithRootViewController:settingsPopoverView];


popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
popover.delegate = self;
popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 497);
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:Button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

then later in my code, once the user makes a selection in the first popover window

```
//screen navigation call when selection is made
[self.navigationController pushViewController:selectionView animated:YES];
```

Again, this grouping of code animates my nav bar, and auto generates a back button with a wrong label on the next view.  I need to stop the animation of JUST the nav bar and alter the label of the back button.

Thanks

Comment: In examples where you've seen this, is the main view change being animated or not?

Comment: Its a grouped list view, and it slides to the left offscreen while the new view comes on screen.  So as far as I can tell, yes its still animated while the nav bar is not.  It simply looks as if the nav bar at the top of the screen always stays constant while the views under it animate when changed.

Comment: Not sure how that's done. I thought I could do it be using a custom navigation controller with a custom NavigationBar that would just override pushNavigationItem:animated: and pass NO to the superclass, but that didn't work. That method is never called by the navigation controller (In my test, the navigation controller did have my custom bar, and its init and setItems:animated: method were called). I don't know how the navigation controller is telling its navigation bar to animate.

Comment: Right, I've been playing around with the popNavigationItemAnimated and pushNavigationItem methods, but neither seem to be having any effect.

Comment: I wonder, if in the examples you saw, they were using a tool bar, and controlling it manually. Did the back button have the usual look?

Comment: Actually no, at second glance the back button is just a basic rectangle button design.  So I guess it is some kind of custom bar.  Although its possible they only made a custom back button too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23517/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jesse-durham)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. In the storyboard I added a navigation bar to the top of a view controller, and a container view below it, taking up the rest of the screen. I deleted the view controller that came with the container view and replaced it with a navigation controller. I unchecked the navigation controller's "Shows Navigation Bar" box in the inspector. I added sever other controllers that had buttons connected to segues to push to the next one in line, and gave those controllers titles. In the first controller, the one with the container view, I added this code:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *bar;
    UINavigationController *nav;
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
    UIBarButtonItem *done;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    nav  = (UINavigationController *)self.childViewControllers[0];
    nav.delegate = self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:viewController.title];
    if (done == nil) done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked)];
    [item setRightBarButtonItem:done];

    if (navigationController.viewControllers.count >1) {
        if (backButton == nil)  backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backToPrevious)];
        [item setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];
        [bar setItems:@[item] animated:NO];
    }else{
        [bar setItems:@[item] animated:NO];
    }
}

-(void)backToPrevious {
    [nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)doneClicked {
    NSLog(@"Done Clicked");
}
```